# Postgres max field length issue

Tags: postgres-9.4

We are trying to load some data in postgres
The problem is data is huge that its exceeding character varying(10485760) limit.

Is there any possible way to increase this limit?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXT data type. It will allow you to enter long data.
Use ALTER ... command for column data type.